# i want to paste selected text in a text view on button click named paste.how can i do this?

Tags: cocoa

I am new to cocoa prgramming, and I am copying text using the code:

```
NSRange range = [textView selectedRange];
NSData* rtfData = [textView RTFFromRange: range];
NSAttributedString* aStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithRTF:rtfData documentAttributes:NULL];
NSString* str = [aStr string];
```

`str` contains the selected text, but how can I paste that text in a [`NSTextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) whenever I click in a textview?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set delegate of NSTextView to self, then you need to implement delegate method on which you want to perform this action.

And then you can use setString method of NSText(Super class of NSTextView) to set the text.

Edit - (Try with this first, if it set the text to textview)

```
NSRange range = [textView selectedRange]; 
NSData* rtfData = [textView RTFFromRange: range];
NSAttributedString* aStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithRTF:rtfData documentAttributes:NULL];
NSString* str = [aStr string];
[[textView setString:str];
```

Comment: this thing is not working.after selecting text and clicking on copy button. when i press paste button it empty the text view.

Answer (score 0):

for NSTextView you need :

```
[[textView textStorage] setAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str]];
```